# Returning string from a remote server using rpcgen

Tags: rpc, xml-rpc

I am going through RPC tutorial and learn few techniques in rpcgen. I have the idea of adding, multiplying different data types using rpcgen.

But I have not found any clue that how could I declare a function in .x file which will return a string. Actually I am trying to build a procedure which will return a random string(rand string array is in server).

Can any one advise me how to proceed in this issue? It will be helpful if you advise me any tutorial regarding this returning string/pointer issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, answering to the original question (more than 2 years old), the first answer is correct but a little tricky.

In your .x file, you define your structure with the string inside, having defined previously the size of the string:

```
typedef string str_t<255>;

struct my_result {
    str_t data;
};
...
```

Then you invoke rpcgen on your .x file to generate client and server stubs and .xdr file:

```
$rpcgen -N *file.x*
```

Now you can compile client and server in addition to any program where you pretend to use the remote functions. To do so, I followed the "repcgen Tutorial" in ORACLE's web page:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1435/rpcgenpguide-21470/index.html

The tricky part is, although you defined a string of size *m* (array of m characters) what rpcgen and .xdr file create is a pointer to allocated memmory. Something like this:

.h file

```
typedef char *str_t;                                                                                                                        

struct my_result {                                                              
    int res;                                                                    
    str_t data;                                                                 
};                                                                              
typedef struct my_result my_result;
```

.xdr file

```
bool_t xdr_str_t (XDR *xdrs, str_t *objp)                                              
{                                                                               
    register int32_t *buf;                                                      

     if (!xdr_string (xdrs, objp, 255))                                         
         return FALSE;                                                          
    return TRUE;                                                                
}
```

So just take into account when using this structure in your server side that it is not a string of size m, but a char pointer for which you'll have to reserve memory before using it or you'll be prompted the same error than me on execution:

```
Segmentation fault!
```

To use it on the server you can write:

```
static my_result response;                                                 
static char text[255];                                                      

memset(&response, '\0', sizeof(my_result));                                
memset(text, '\0', sizeof(text));                                           

response.data = text;
```

And from there you are ready to use it wisely! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [XDR protocol specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629799/chap3.htm) you can define a string type where m is the length of the string in bytes:

> The standard defines a string of n (numbered 0 to n -1) bytes to be the number n encoded as an unsigned integer (as described above), and followed by the n bytes of the string. Each byte must be regarded by the implementation as being 8-bit transparent data. This allows use of arbitrary character set encodings. Byte m of the string always precedes byte m +1 of the string, and byte 0 of the string always follows the string's length. If n is not a multiple of four, then the n bytes are followed by enough (0 to 3) residual zero bytes, r, to make the total byte count a multiple of four.

```
string object<m>;
```

You can then define a struct with the string type `str_t` as one of the variables:

```
typedef string str_t<255>;

struct my_result {
    str_t data;
};
```

Then in your .x file you can define an RPC in your program which returns a struct of type `my_result`. Since rpcgen will give you a pointer to this struct (which I have called res) you can print the message with `prinf("%s\n", res->data);`.

```
program HELLO_PROG {
    version HELLO_VERSION {
        my_result abc() = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 1000;
```